Can a unitary $U$ transform $H = aX + bY + cZ$ to $U^\dagger H U = -aX + bY + cZ$?
I am wondering whether there exists a unitary operation $U$ that can transform a given Hamiltonian of the form $H = aX + bY + cZ$, where $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are the Pauli matrices, into another Hamiltonian $U^\dagger H U = -aX + bY + cZ$ for any values of the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$. In other words, the task is to find a unitary $U$ that flips the sign of the $X$ component while leaving the $Y$ and $Z$ components unchanged. For example, if $H = aX + cZ$, then this unitary would be just $U = Z$. However, if we include $Y$, I'm wondering if there exists such $U$. I doubt there exists, but I am not sure how to prove the claim.

Short answer: if $\xi\in\mathbb R$ is chosen such that $e^{2i\xi}=\frac{-a+ib}{a+ib}$, then $U={\rm diag}(e^{i\xi},e^{-i\xi})$ is the unitary you are looking for.

First of all, there is an abstract argument that guarantees its existence: Defining $H_0=aX+bY+cZ$ and $H_1=-aX+bY+cZ$ it is easy to compute that both $H_0$ and $H_1$ have eigenvalues $\lambda_\pm=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$. Thus there exist unitaries $U_0,U_1$ such that
\begin{align*}
H_0&=U_0{\rm diag}(\lambda_+,\lambda_-)U_0^\dagger\\
H_1&=U_1{\rm diag}(\lambda_+,\lambda_-)U_1^\dagger\,.
\end{align*}
Therefore the unitary $U:=U_0U_1^\dagger$ satisfies the desired identity $U^\dagger H_0U=H_1$.
Now for finding this $U$ one can either pursue the aforementioned diagonalization strategy, or one can start from a generic special unitary $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
V=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi)e^{i\xi}&\sin(\phi)e^{i\omega}\\
-\sin(\phi)e^{-i\omega}&\cos(\phi)e^{-i\xi}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and compute $VH_0V^\dagger$ & compare it to $H_1$. Doing so shows that the off-diagonals of $VH_0V^\dagger$ feature a term $ce^{\pm i(\omega+\xi)}\sin(2\phi)$ meaning—because the off-diagonal has to be $-a\pm ib$—we can choose $\phi$ to be $0$. In other words the diagonal unitary $V={\rm diag}(e^{i\xi},e^{-i\xi})$ has to satisfy
$$
V^\dagger H_0V =\begin{pmatrix}c&(a-ib)e^{-2i\xi}\\(a+ib)e^{2i\xi}&-c\end{pmatrix}\overset!=\begin{pmatrix}c&-a-ib\\-a+ib&-c\end{pmatrix}=H_1\,.
$$
This shows that $\xi\in\mathbb R$ has to be chosen such that $(a+ib)e^{2i\xi}=-a+ib$; note that such a choice is always possible because both $a+ib,-a+ib$ have absolute value $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so they only differ by a phase.
